# Android Service START_STICKY, service not always restarted when app killed

Tags: android, service, kill, restart, sticky

I have a Android Service which its purpose is to run in background and receieve locations

```
public class Myservice extends Service implements

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
 ... 
  all necessary init etc..
  return START_STICKY
}
```

My application has only 1 activity that simply runs startService when started.

When I kill the app from the TaskManager, sometimes the service is recreated sometimes no...

I cannot figure out why not how to debug it.

Maybe I have some code in my service that makes the service fail to start sometimes?
What could cause this? How could I trace and debug this ?

Android SDK 23 (Android 5.1)

Comment: Referring the [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) It does not guarantee of restarting of the service in certain conditions. Use AlarmManager

Comment: It even should not restart the service. If the users stops it, the service should not start again by itself

Comment: It does though (I kill the app from the manager and the onStartCommand of the service restart after 2-3 seconds)